# Position the dropdown-list of select on top of the select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the easiest/best way of positioning the the dropdown-list of select box to float on top of the select box instead of just popping up below/above it as by default?

Here's a picture of what I want:
[image: Floating select dropdown-list]

The number of options in the select will vary from 10 to more than 1000, so the ability to scroll is still needed.

Pure CSS3 is preferred, but any other method (js, jquery, etc.) is also very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a plugin or code your own "select box" -- if you are using a real HTML `<select>`, there is no cross-browser way to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any plugin able to do this? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Try [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+plugin+select+replacement) -- there are lots of options out there.  For me, the first result is http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/, which at least looks reasonable.

Comment: Thank you, I think selectBoxIt will be able to do it with a little tweaking.